# Yii 2 code formatter to display xml with code highlighting in html, string highlighter

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Does anyone have experience with the things from the title of question?
I'll try to use: `http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/`
but if anyone have something better, and share it with me, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for it, so I have a string that needs to be style and then echo it:

```
<span style='color:#a65700; '>&lt;</span><span style='color:#5f5035; '>id</span><span style='color:#a65700; '>></span>{$product->attributes['id']}<span style='color:#a65700; '>&lt;/</span><span style='color:#5f5035; '>id</span><span style='color:#a65700; '>></span>
```

Result will be, string with xml tag with an appropriate color:

```
<id>10</id>
```